# How to return the Pop-up instead of view in ActionMethod

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog, popup

I have a form in which user is entering passengers data which includes (Name, SeatNo, Sequence No and e.tc).
and if any of the passenger data is already checked-in. I am returning the view which is showing The following Passenger has already checked in.

So this is all working so fine but what i want is when there is a data of any passenger which is already checked in instead of returning the new view I want to show popup with Message.

This is my Checkedin-View

```
@model Marhaba.Models.PassengerInfo

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CheckIn";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    var FlightNoList = ViewBag.FlightNoList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>;
    var category = ViewBag.Passcategory as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>;
}
<section id="contact-us-section" class="contact-us-section pb-30 image-bg">
    <div class="container">
        <br />
        <div class="slider-text-2 text-center pt-40">
            <h2 class="font-w-8 font-30 ltr-s-1 pb-12 color-w" style="color:#e60053">Regular Passengers</h2>
            <h4 class="color-w font-22"><a class="font-20 color-w" href="/Home/Index">Home</a></h4>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="section">
            <div class="container" >
                <div class="">
                    <!-- Contact Form Start -->
                    <div class="form-box clearfix">
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("CheckIn", "PassengerInfo", FormMethod.Post))
                        {
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required", placeholder = "Name" } })
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SeatNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class="form-control", required = "required", placeholder = "Seat Number" } })
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>     
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SequenceNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required", placeholder = "Sequence Number" } })
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FlightId, FlightNoList, new { @class = "form-control", required = "required", placeholder = "Flight Id " })
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryID, category, new { @class = "form-control", required = "required", placeholder = "Flight Id " })
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6 checkbox">
                                <label>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.isGuest, new { @class = "", @id = "Check", onchange = "valueChanged()" }) With Guest</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NoOfGuests, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "GuestsNo", placeholder = "No Of Guests", style = "display: none;" } })
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Remarks, new { @class="form-control", placeholder = "Comments", rows = "6" })
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-12"  >
                                <input style="float: right; background-color:white; color: #e60053 "  type="Submit" class="btn" value="Check In" onmouseover=" this.style.backgroundColor = '#e60053', this.style.color = 'white' " onmouseout="    this.style.backgroundColor = 'white',   this.style.color = '#e60053'">
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <!-- Contact Form End -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my Action method here you can see I am returning the view which is **RecordDublicate**.

```
 public ActionResult CheckIn(PassengerInfo Data)
    {
        if (!General.ValidateSession())
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "User");
        }
        if (!(ModelState.IsValid))
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Form Data is Invalid";
            return RedirectToAction("CheckOut");
        }
        if (Data.NoOfGuests == null)
        {
            Data.NoOfGuests = "0";
        }
        if (Data.Remarks == null)
        {
            Data.Remarks = "No Comments";
        }
        if(Data.RefSeatNo==null)
        {
            Data.RefSeatNo = "No Reference";
        }
        Data.CheckinTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
        Data.CheckoutTime = null;
        Data.IsCheckout = false;
        Data.isFeedBack = false;
        Data.EnterBy = Session["UserName"].ToString();
        Data.Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        var result = repository.SearchDublicate(Data.SequenceNo, Data.FlightId, Data.Date);
        if(result >= 1)
        {
            return View("RecordDublicate");
        }
        repository.AddRecord(Data);
        repository.SaveRecord();
        return RedirectToAction("Scaning");
    }
```

This is my RecordDublicate view

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<link href="~/Contents/css/InvalidEmail.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="terminal">
    <h1>Error <span class="errorcode">404</span></h1>
    @*<p class="output">unauthorized access</p>*@
    <p class="output">The Passenger has already checked-in</p>
    <div class="buttons">
        <a class="button" href="/Home/Index">Go to Home</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is all working fine , I just want to return the popup view on the same screen , instead of returning the new view.

Comment: Have you used bootstrap modal for this? This can be achieve via bootstrap modal with the help of AJAX.

Comment: it would be appreciated if you can provide any reference

Comment: Okay wait, I will create one for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

HTML:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="fncShow();">
    Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="divToPopulate">
         @*Populate content here.*@
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is the script code:

```
<script>
    function fncShow() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ShowDialog", "Home")',
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                  $('#divToPopulate').html(data);
                  $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
            },
            error: function (a1) {
                console.log(a1);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Here is the view that I want to show on the body of my modal (Filename: _MyView.cshtml):

```
<h2>_MyView</h2>
<p>Hello World</p>
```

Here is the part of the controller that will return the Partial View that will populate Div ID: **divToPopulate**

```
 public PartialViewResult ShowDialog()
    {
        return PartialView("_MyView");
    }
```

Here is the sample output:

[image]

Make sure you reference JQuery and Bootstrap on your code.